# xrspatial module in python not found

Tags: python, anaconda, python-xarray, python-module

I want to use the python module xrspatial.

For this I installed xrspatial on anaconda like this:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xarray-spatial
```

But when I try to use it e.g.

```
from xrspatial.convolution import circle_kernel
```

I receive the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xrspatial'

Does anybody know why this module seems not to be found?
Thanks in advance!